# Reading GDAL Data from Tiff images Encoded as a Base64String

Tags: c#, base64, tiff, gdal

I am currently trying to decode a (Geo)Tiff Image encoded as a Base64String back to the original format using C# so that I can access the GDAL Metadata as for example the Dataset.

**Problem 1**: I can't find any exact explanation on how to convert a Base64String encoded image to a tiff image. The method I found only returns null for `tiff`.

```
        Tiff tiff;
        String base64String = imageDataString.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""); // data:image/png;base64,
        byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
        tiff =  Tiff.ClientOpen("in-memory", "r", ms, new TiffStream());
```

using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.

**Problem 2:**
If the tiff image was decoded, how do I save it to the harddrive? This step seems to be necessary so that I can open the image to extract the GDAL Dataset as following:

```
            Dataset GdalRoomSet = Gdal.Open(imagePath, 0);
            double[] TransformationCoefficients = new double[6];
            GdalRoomSet.GetGeoTransform(TransformationCoefficients);
```

Comment: Did you check the value of base64String after `String base64String = imageDataString.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");`? You wrote that you have a tiff, but the data url has the type `png`. And to write a file, just write the byteBuffer in binary mode to a file.

Comment: @jps Thank you so much. I totally overlooked the different file format. Seems like I need a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved itselfe through jps' comment. The question is now obsolete, as I need a completely different approach.